# Transform Rows to Columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My input data will be in below format

```
id     value
1.1    Test
1.2    AA-BB-CC
```

I need to transform this into the below format

```
ProductCode    ProductType
AA-BB-CC            Test
```

Id values will be static and will not change.

Could you help me how can I do it in spark/scala please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot `id` then rename the resulting columns :

```
val df1 = df.groupBy()
  .pivot("id")
  .agg(first("value"))
  .withColumnRenamed("1.1", "ProductType")
  .withColumnRenamed("1.2", "ProductCode")

df1.show

//+-----------+-----------+
//|ProductType|ProductCode|
//+-----------+-----------+
//|       Test|   AA-BB-CC|
//+-----------+-----------+
```